# nginx as Apache front-end: how to redirect some image files?

Tags: apache, nginx, redirect

I am using nginx as front-end to Apache server to serve static files, mostly images like this:

```
   location / {
   expires 15m;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   }

  location ~* \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|svg)$ {
   expires 1M;
  }
```

Question: how can I redirect permanently **some** image files to new location?

If it was Apache, I would use the following directives:

```
Redirect permanent /deleted_dir/some_image.gif                                     /image/some_image.gif
Redirect permanent /deleted_dir/other_image.gif                                    /image/new_image.jpg
```

How can I do it with nginx?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that the nginx "rewrite" directive makes the job:

```
        rewrite ^/deleted_dir/some_image.gif$     /image/some_image.gif permanent;
        rewrite ^/deleted_dir/other_image.gif$    /image/new_image.jpg permanent;
```